# Why sometimes first members of enums in linux kernel are initialized with 0

Tags: c, linux, enums, linux-kernel

I've noticed in linux kernel source code, that some enums definition have first member of enum explicitly initialized with 0 as follows:

```
enum i2c_adapter_type {
    I2C_ADAPTER_SMBUS = 0,
    I2C_ADAPTER_VGADDC,
    I2C_ADAPTER_PANEL,
    I2C_ADAPTER_DESIGNWARE_0,
    I2C_ADAPTER_DESIGNWARE_1,
};
```

Code snippet available here at chromeos_laptop.c:56

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/chrome/chromeos_laptop.c

Can someone explain me, what is the purpose of doing such a construct ? I know that first enum member is guaranteed to be 0 by later C standards (ANSI, C99 and so on), so why people are doing this ?

Comment: Self documenting code.    I've been writing C, since the K&R first edition was a new book.  Even then, the first entry in an `enum`, if not specifically set to some other value, was always 0

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While this is not a syntactic necessity, usually the zero is inserted by the programmer to make the semantics of the enum members clear to the reader. A reason could be that the enums are used as index to an array, or as ID for some external resource. It is a hint that changing the enum (removing, adding, reordering) may have repercussions, though an additional comment is a good idea. Which is there in this case, in line 55 where it belongs:

```
/* Keep this enum consistent with i2c_adapter_names */
```

This pattern could be extended to explicitely providing the values for each member, e. g. if it may happen that entries are removed when they become obsolete and you want to keep the gap or the absolute values for some reason:

```
static const char *i2c_adapter_names[] = {
    "SMBus I801 adapter",
    "i915 gmbus vga",
    "<unsupported>",
    "Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter",
    "Synopsys DesignWare I2C adapter",
};

enum i2c_adapter_type {
    I2C_ADAPTER_SMBUS = 0,
    I2C_ADAPTER_VGADDC = 1,
    /*I2C_ADAPTER_PANEL = 2,*/
    I2C_ADAPTER_DESIGNWARE_0 = 3,
    I2C_ADAPTER_DESIGNWARE_1 = 4,
};
```

### Addition

As for `UNPROBED` and its siblings in `i2c_peripheral_state`, this has also a special meaning: That enum is used in the struct `i2c_peripheral`, and 0 is the default value when you use `memset(…, 0, sizeof(…))` (I'm not a fan of it due to possible side effects) or an initializer list (should be preferred) to initialize the struct. So the state `UNPROBED` is the default when no other value is explicitely assigned, as can be seen in a couple of places where instances of this struct are assigned, e. g. [line 429](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/platform/chrome/chromeos_laptop.c#L429).

And a protip as bonus: It's much easier to follow the usage of identifiers with the [Linux cross reference](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/latest/ident/i2c_peripheral_state).

Comment: thanks for the answer, it really make sense for the enum at chromeos_laptop.c:56, although I'm used to mark enums vulnerable to moving, adding and removing with explicit comment. However I'm wondering what you will say about enum at chromeos_laptop.c:64, which as far as I've checked is not index of any array.

Comment: thank you very much for addition, I'd never think that this could be a reason. If you have more knowledge about this black magic, please post it.

Comment: Black magic? Absolutely not. I'd call it best practices, shaped by experience over literally millions of man hours. That means **hard work**, no magic involved. Want to learn more? You could start [here](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/hacker-howto.html), as well as at [dozens of other places](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=programming+blog), then continue reading, coding and gaining experience. And have a good time!

Comment: Thank Murphy one more time for the advice and take care